# Compiler crashes when building OpenCV 3.0 with VC14 platform toolset

Tags: visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0, internal-compiler-error

I am trying to compile the latest version of OpenCV (3.0) using the Visual Studio 2015 C/C++ compiler.

I have downloaded the latest source code from GitHub and generated the solution with CMake 3.4.0-rc1. I only want to build the library **without any additional features** (Contrib module, CUDA, VTK, OpenNI, etc.)

After I generate the solution (CMake doesn't show any errors) I'm trying to build it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. After the build starts, a window pops-up telling that the **"Microsoft C/C++ compiler driver has stopped working"** and it closes automatically in a sort period.

[image: Compiler error]

When the build stops, I get the following errors:

[image]

My **bin** and **lib** folders are **empty** (no dlls/libs are generated).

When the compiler crashes, in the Output window I get the following error:

```
1>D:\OPENCV-BUILD-VC14\cmake-output-3\modules\core\opencv_core_pch.cpp : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 246)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the compiler. Either OpenCV offers (or will offer after a bug report) a workaround or you have to switch the compiler. Maybe you can figure out some compiler setting that will not trigger the ICE, but maybe such settings not exists at all.

Please report this bug both to Microsoft and OpenCV. AT least with Visual Studio 2015 RC1 this seems to be a known issue: http://code.opencv.org/issues/4376

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 isn't supported for OpenCV CUDA modules yet (although it works fine for all non-CUDA modules).  VS2013 is the latest compiler supported for CUDA.  See this system requirements page: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements

Comment: I have mentioned that I am trying to build the library without CUDA support :-)